# Can you still make use of the fargate compute type when using "EKS Anywhere"

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, aws-fargate, hybrid-cloud

EKS Anywhere lets you install aws eks on your on-prem hardware but can you link your eks anywhere cluster to your aws account to take advantage of the fargate compute that standard eks offers?

Comment: If you could, what benefit would EKS Anywhere provide? I'm not sure I understand the reasoning, either. Typically the control plane is much more difficult to manage than the nodes.

Comment: It would mean you could, for example, use your on prem resources for the bulk of your work load and use fargate nodes as a burst capacity. I mean I can think of more but I find your question more confusing are you saying that EKS anywhere would somehow be less beneficial if it had the additional (and optional) functionality of being able to leverage fargate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...can you link your eks anywhere cluster to your aws account to take advantage of the fargate compute that standard eks offers ?

Currently, Fargate is not supported with EKS Anywhere. See "Serverless" [here](https://anywhere.eks.amazonaws.com/docs/concepts/eksafeatures/#comparing-amazon-eks-anywhere-to-amazon-eks). The same applies to Outposts.